# Why is there no simple inbult conveter for Date to LocalDate in java?

Tags: java, date

Curious about the design choice - is there any authoritative source about the design decision to not have a simple converter for LocalDate -> Date and viceversa baked into the LocalDate object?

I'm fed up of moving these objects around with the completely clunky

```
java.util.Date.from(dateToConvert.atStartOfDay()
  .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
  .toInstant());
```

and the other one,

```
dateToConvert.toInstant()
  .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
  .toLocalDateTime();
```

And while i know I cannot have date.toLocalDate(nullable ZoneId), it would at least be of some use to know why (*if only so I never ever justify a decision using the same logic*).

Comment: My guess: They wanted to make it clear to the programmer that the conversion requires deciding on a time zone and that s/he has the responsibility for choosing one.

Comment: @OleV.V. but they don't - you can just spam in that "ZoneId" thing. It's not like anyone is really bothering to work out "oh what is the ZoneId", I mean - developers are just going to cut/paste that code in and get on with, you know, solving the actual business issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might as well ask why there is no built in conversion method to turn a File object into an integer: The 2 types are almost entirely unrelated.

But, I hear you say, hold the phone, rzwitserloot! What the heck are you on about? `Date` and `LocalDate` are *unrelated*???

Yes, they are.

Because `java.util.Date` is a silly name. That's *NOT* what `j.u.Date` represents; that's why all the date-related methods in this object are deprecated. Once you see that a class named `Date` has a method called `getHours` that should hopefully be a good indication that whomever named it was, let's just go with 'having an off day'. **That aint no date**.

`j.u.Date` represents 'a moment in time'. It is the exact equivalent to `java.time.Instant`. Its internal storage is a single long representing epoch-millis **and nothing more**.

This has almost no relationship whatsoever with `LocalDate`.

Yes, *MANY* systems use a `j.u.Date` object as a way to represent the same notion that `LocalDate` is trying to represent, but that is *because those systems messed up*, and are using an entirely inappropriate type for it. They may be excused; they just fell for the same trap you did: They got thrown off by the name of this class.

Perhaps one might argue: Okay, but, hey, we live in this world and not a fairytale one, so given that so many times 'I need to convert this `j.u.Date` to `LocalDate`' comes up, it should be easier, right? Well, enabling bad behaviour just because it is common – let's just say the word is out on whether that's a good idea. Also, that job rather fundamentally is very very tricky. How do we do this conversion? Should I take the moment in time as represented by the `j.u.Date` object, check out what the actual calendar date is in the current system default locale (as in, go to where the server is. Now go out the building. Find a person. Ask them: What date is it right now? What do they answer?) – or should they go UTC locale? (Go to Greenwich and ask there. Unless it is summer, then ask: What date was it one hour ago?).

**The answers obviously won't be the same** in many cases, and yet neither strategy is obviously superior to the other. Thus, making such a convenience method is just going to cause epic reams of confusion. You're missing a crucial bit of info, if not more – the job of converting a `j.u.Date` to a `LocalDate` cannot be done without further context unless you're willing to just toss a coin on every missing bit of info you have. You might as well invoke a `Random` instance's `.nextInt(365)` to figure it out.

Comment: NB: And as 'proof' that j.u.Date is the old API equivalent to j.t.Instant, Date __DOES__ have a method called 'toInstant'. Because THAT conversion is sensible and can be done with no further information required.

Comment: this is a good answer - and i'll probably mark it correct unless there's an authoritative source - but given the whole point of coding is to reduce time, it is just irritating when people make design decisions that lengthen development time